# How to uninstall Dissenter Browser in Kubuntu

Tags: uninstall, browser, purge

I use Kubuntu.

I want to unistall Dissenter but when I use `sudo apt-get purge Disstener` or `sudo apt-get remove Disstener` it does not work.

If you know other way to uninstall it please tell me.

Comment: How did you install it? Please edit your question to include the full text of all error messages you receive, "it does not work" is not sufficient. Edit in the text, do not paste in a screenshot.

Comment: Guys I'm sorry i reinstall the Kubuntu because i have other problems so now i don't have this browser because i reinstall the Kubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dissenter Browser was shipped as snap. To remove it use command below:

```
snap remove dissenter-browser
```

If you are sure that it was installed as deb-package - use:

```
sudo apt-get remove dissenter-browser
```

Comment: i didn't have this browser now but i know this way is true because i forgot to write "dissenter-browser" and i write just "dissenter"

Answer (score 1):

In agreement with what N0rbet has posted, just add that you can check [this](https://www.imaginelinux.com/uninstall-programs-from-ubuntu-system/) post where they quickly help you with the task.

You may find it useful

Comment: This is good answer too but "N0rbert" give me completely answer